# Is locale also supported by the Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, locale

In Linux, timer is supported by kernel. Time is relate to locale. Is locale also supported by the Linux kernel, or a  user-space construct; the kernel doesn’t care about that? Thanks.

Comment: No, the kernel has absolutely no idea of locales or of the (unrelated) time zones. The kernel keeps the time in UTC (even when the real time clock is set to local time), and the userland does the transformation based on user's settings. Different users can use different time zones and everything's fine.

Comment: @mosvy I don't think kernel cares about UTC or local time, it just keeps the time, interpretation of this wall time value purely depends on userland.

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克 what's the point of your comment? are you suggesting that you can configure the userland to treat the time it gets from the kernel as anything else than Epoch/UTC? That's **not** possible. `gettimeofday(2)` and `time(2)` always return seconds since 1.1.1970 **UTC**. The kernel has some workarounds for filesystems that are using localtime but that, while interesting, is completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Linux kernel tracks seconds past 1/1/1970 00:00:00 UTC, commonly called "epoch time".  There's some kludges around leap seconds, but that's about it.

There's a second kludge for how this time value gets initialised from the hardware real-time clock (RTC) at boot time because the RTC may not be set to UTC.   (Thanks, Microsoft).

Timezones, locales and similar are all user space constructs and not part of the kernel.

Comment: @derobert Indeed, silly me. Too long without using MS "#$"#$.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro BTW, Windows has supported RTC set to UTC since at least 7. https://superuser.com/questions/975717/does-windows-10-support-utc-as-bios-time has 10, and links to 7 & 8

Comment: @derobert Thanks for the comments....off-topic: fortunately no Windows on sight at home, and negociated from day 0 a Mac or Linux corporate notebook...we are maybe half a dozen users using Linux out of thousands of people.

Comment: We should not thank Microsoft without also thanking the hardware vendors that make systems without real-time clocks.  (-:  Also note that there _are_ timezones in the kernel, in a filesystem that you may have heard of.  http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/system-manager.html#SystemClock

Comment: It seems that kernel DO has a part related to timezone, although it's obsolete and nobody ever use it. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/gettimeofday.2.html